# Facing issue while creating maven project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Not able to create maven project in eclipse, error occurring which is given below screen shots.

[image]

and below error logs.

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users[user].m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users[user].m2\repository)

Comment: Your OS and Eclipse are pretty outdated. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com). Your issue might caused by Maven Central moved from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: The real issue is to use RELEASE as a version instead of a real one apart from updating your environment.